# count in case statement SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below query in my sql program

```
SELECT
    m.managerid,
    CASE
        WHEN (ISNULL(COUNT(t.employeeid), 0) = 0) THEN 'No Manager'
        ELSE COUNT(m.managerid)
    END
FROM employee t
LEFT JOIN employenrol m
    ON t.employeeid = m.employeeid
GROUP BY t.employeeid
```

`if count(t.employeeid)= 0` I need to display **no manager** else the actual count.

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'No Manager' to
>   data type int. Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or
>   other SET operation.

How to fix this?

Comment: your query doesn't give a good idea of your data structure.. everyone is just guessing the answer here because you're counting the employeeid from employee  which is your main table in your query that should not logically have a null employeeid..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

> The data types of else_result_expression and any result_expression
>   must be the same or must be an implicit conversion.

You need to do *explicit conversion* in `else` part since the first `then` statement returns `VARCHAR` which cannot be converted to `INT`.

```
SELECT t.employeeid, 
       CASE 
         WHEN Count(m.employeeid) = 0 THEN 'No Manager' 
         ELSE Cast(Count(m.employeeid) AS VARCHAR(50)) 
       END 
FROM   employee t 
       LEFT JOIN employenrol m 
              ON t.employeeid = m.employeeid 
GROUP  BY t.employeeid
```

Also `Count` aggregate returns `0` when there you have `NULL`. No need to use `ISNULL` function

Comment: I'm surprised this even compiled

Comment: @JamieD77 - Yep, didnt check the alias and column names.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
Select m.managerid,
    Case When count(t.employeeid) =0 Then 'No Manager' Else count(m.managerid) end  
From 
    employee t Left Join employenrol m On t.employeeid=m.employeeid 
Group By t.employeeid
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're wanting to do..

```
SELECT  t.employeeid,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(m.managerid) = 0 THEN 'No Manager'
             ELSE CAST(COUNT(m.managerid) AS VARCHAR(10))
        END
FROM    employee t
        LEFT JOIN employenrol m ON t.employeeid = m.employeeid
GROUP BY t.employeeid
```

not sure why you would select m.managerid and count t.employeeid which would give an error since you're only grouping by t.employeeid

this might even perform better for you

```
SELECT  t.employeeid,
        CASE WHEN m.managercount = '0' THEN 'No Manager'
             ELSE m.managercount
        END
FROM    @employee t
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT CAST(COUNT(managerid) AS VARCHAR(10)) managercount
                     FROM   @employenrol m
                     WHERE  t.employeeid = m.employeeid
                    ) m
```

Comment: Your second query will not produce the same result as OP expected if employee table has duplicate `employeeid` if in case

Comment: @Prdp that's true.. they'd have to use distinct which would probably drop the performance to match the first query